# How to pass serial communication object from one callback to another callback in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have created a button which on press will send data 's' to  microcontroller and another button which on pressing needs to send 'g' to microcontroller .But the problem is that how can i send data using same serial communication object.I tried passing s using guidata but din't work.
Can anyone help . I am new to matlab.

matlab code:

//first button

```
 function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 s = serial('COM2');
 set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
 set(s,'Timeout',10);
 set(s,'ReadAsyncMode','continuous');
 fopen(s);
 fprintf(s,'%c','s');
 guidata(hObject,s);
```

//second button

```
 function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 s = guidata(hObject);
 fopen(s);
 fprintf(s,'%c','g');
 fclose(s)
 delete(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `guidata` and `handles` in the right way. I would think you'll need something like:

//first button

```
 function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 s = serial('COM2');
 set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
 set(s,'Timeout',10);
 set(s,'ReadAsyncMode','continuous');
 fopen(s);
 fprintf(s,'%c','s');
 handles.s = s;
 guidata(hObject,handles);
```

//second button

```
 function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 s = handles.s;
 fopen(s);
 fprintf(s,'%c','g');
 fclose(s)
 delete(s)
```

Think of it like this. `handles` is a big variable (a struct) that contains references to all the parts of your GUI in each of its fields.

It is stored in the parent figure of your GUI, and gets passed in to every GUI callback, so that the callback functions can refer to various parts of the GUI if they need to.

You can also store your own things in fields of `handles` (here we've stored your serial object `s` in a field called `handles.s`) - but if you do this, you need to refresh `handles` before the function ends, so that later callbacks get your updated version. That's what `guidata` does - it pushes your updated `handles` up to the ancestor of `hObject`, which is the parent figure of the GUI. Once that is done, later callbacks such as `stop_callback` get the updated `handles`, which now has `s` stored in a field, and it can be retrieved and used.

Comment: thanx a lot great explanation.I searched a lot on google but your explanation goes into my head.